# how to get the parameter in html

Tags: javascript, html

I create the html for `Label` & `text box` and `OK` button.

I just pass parameter from the javascript like that

```
../test/Html/MWD.Numeric.html?id=1.0000
```

I would like to set that id value in my text box @html.

How to set the id in text box. When I updated that id in html, I would like to update in parent screen.

How to do? Please kindly guide me. Thank in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: No . I would to get value in html. Not Javascript

Comment: far as I know, it's not possible in html but you can use the <script> tag and enter your JavaScript there, why you don't want to use JavaScript?!?

Comment: You need to use the `encodeURI(..)` to pass the URL as a  parameter.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?rq=1)

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")); }
```

Comment: better to give link to that question in comment.